# The probability of winning in less than 10 rounds of dice roll with 3 players

Tags: probability

Three persons are rolling dice: who throws the greatest roll is the winner. But even if two of the players have the same score, the game starts agains. What is the probability of the winning of the first player in less than 10 rounds?

I've tried to solve it with a naive approach and have been getting an unplausible answer of $0,27$. Does it look like truth?

Comment: How did you end up with that answer and why does it sound unplausible? In particular, what is your naive approach?

Comment: The place to start is the chance of a winner in a single round. Have you calculated that?  What did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The chance of having some winner in a given round is the chance that the three dice are all different.  Can you calculate that?  Call the answer $p$.  Then the chance to have no winner in one round is $(1-p)$  To have no winner in $n$ rounds, you need to have $(1-p)$ every round, so it is $(1-p)^n$

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at this question is that probability of winning in less than 10 ten rounds for each player is same coz everyone has identical die.

And then there is probability that game goes beyond 9 rounds.

Sum of all 4 probabilities is of course 1.

Can you calculate the probability that game goes beyond 9 rounds like this

(wasn't decided in 1st round) * (wasn't decided in 2nd round) * ....... * (wasn't decided in 9th round)

and then calculate the required probability.

That's all I can say. Maybe someone will come up with a better answer.